# What is wrong with my .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

```
@ECHO OFF
SET m=1 
:namechange
IF EXIST C:\Users\Iree\Pictures\Predator\%m%.bmp (SET m=m+1 | GOTO:namechange) ELSE (GOTO:name) 
:name 
C:\Users\Iree\Pictures\Predator\Command... /preview /quiet /filename %m%.bmp
```

Here is the code. When I run it, it runs a program called `CommandCam.exe`. All you need to know is that it generates a .bmp picture file. I have it currently naming the file with the variable "m", which is working. What is NOT working is my if statement. Right now each time I run it, the previous .bmp file is replaced and the only thing I can generate is a 1.bmp file. Instead, I want to just add another .bmp without replacing anything. For example, if I ran it 5 times, I want 5 separate .bmp files named 1.bmp 2.bmp 3.bmp 4.bmp and 5.bmp.

I just started looking at batch, so help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the final

```
@ECHO OFF
SET m=1
GOTO :namechange
:namechange 
IF EXIST C:\Users\Iree\Pictures\Predator\%m%.bmp (SET /a m+=1) & (GOTO:namechange) ELSE (GOTO:name)
:name
C:\Users\Iree\Pictures\Predator\CommandCam.exe /preview /quiet /filename %m%.bmp
```

Comment: you had an additional space with your original `set m=1 `. To avoid this kind of typo, better use this syntax: `set "m=1"`.

Comment: also, `set m=m+1` needs to be `set /a m=m+1` or `set /a m+=1`

Answer (score 3):

You need `&` not `|` to cascade commands. `|` redirects output.